# click function for each designated class item

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is supposed to correspond with each `li`. With plain JavaScript, I would like to know how to replace the HTML on `listitem` to whatever the user has input.

I would like only the function that is clicked to run, and only for the appropriate row (in this case, li).

```js
function day(el){
var listitem = document.getElementsByClassName('listitem');
var changebox = document.getElementsByClassName('changebox');

listitem[el].innerHTML = changebox[el].value;
}
```

```css
ul li {list-style-type: none;}
.changebox {width: 40px;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
<span class="listitem">Item 1</span>
<input type="text" class="changebox"/>
<button onclick="day(this)">Edit</button>
</li>

<li>
<span class="listitem">Item 1</span>
<input type="text" class="changebox"/>
<button onclick="day(this)">Edit</button>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: `el` is not what you think it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This replaces the entire line item, I didn't know if you wanted the changebox to stay or not and used the *slightly* less verbose queryselector instead of getElementByClassName.

```js
function day(el){
var parent = el.parentNode;
var changebox = parent.querySelector('.changebox')
var listitem = parent.querySelector('.listitem')

listitem.innerHTML = "Item " + changebox.value;
}
```

```css
ul li {list-style-type: none;}
.changebox {width: 40px;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
<span class="listitem">Item 1</span>
<input type="text" class="changebox"/>
<button onclick="day(this)">Edit</button>
</li>

<li>
<span class="listitem">Item 1</span>
<input type="text" class="changebox"/>
<button onclick="day(this)">Edit</button>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: It is mentioned explicitly he would like to replace the text in `listitem`.

Comment: I understood "With plain JavaScript, I would like to know how to replace the HTML on listitem to whatever the user has input." as replace everything but only OP knows :-) In all fairness you should probably get best answer but included mine just to showcase a different method which doesn't require an additional index getter.

Comment: I now see that he refers to "listItem" the class not the list item the element...I guess I read that too fast.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I decided to implement your day function. `el` is not an index but the element it self. So I used that to find the `parentNode` which is the `li` tag containing it. Then from there searched for the first occurrence of the classes you specified for the values.

```js
function day(el){

   var parent = el.parentNode;
   var listitem = parent.getElementsByClassName('listitem')[0];
   var changebox = parent.getElementsByClassName('changebox')[0];

   listitem.innerHTML = changebox.value;
}
```

```css
ul li {list-style-type: none;}
.changebox {width: 40px;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
<span class="listitem">Item 1</span>
<input type="text" class="changebox"/>
<button onclick="day(this)">Edit</button>
</li>

<li>
<span class="listitem">Item 1</span>
<input type="text" class="changebox"/>
<button onclick="day(this)">Edit</button>
</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not considered a good practice to mix your javascript and mark up. you may  consider separating them.
Here is the working code for your example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".listcontainer button").bind('click', day);
});

function day(event) {
  var targetElement = event.target;
  var $targetObject = $(targetElement);
  var siblings = $targetObject.siblings();
  var listitem = siblings.filter('.listitem');
  var changebox = siblings.filter('.changebox');
  $(listitem).html($(changebox).val())
}
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.changebox {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listcontainer">
  <li>
    <span class="listitem">Item 1</span>
    <input type="text" class="changebox" />
    <button class="button">Edit</button>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span class="listitem">Item 1</span>
    <input type="text" class="changebox" />
    <button class="button">Edit</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: OP said he wanted a plain javascript solution.