# How to associate a particular JavaScript function to every button

Tags: javascript, html, button, dom-events, html5-audio

I have successfully made a html page where I am able to create a soundboard of different audio files associated to individual buttons. Each button plays an audio file, and when you click on a different button, the previous audio file stops playing and the next audio file starts playing. For that, I created an `onplay` JavaScript function that applies to all buttons globally on the page.

```
function pauseOthers(ele) 
{
  $("audio").not(ele).each(function (index, audio)
  {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
  });
}
```

Now, if I want to stop playing the audio that is currently selected, I have made a function `Stop()` associated to an `onclick` parameter to stop audio playback associated to the button:

```
function Stop()
{
    var Audio = document.getElementById("sound1");
    if(Audio.paused) {
        Audio.play();
    }
    else {
       Audio.pause(); Audio.currentTime = 0
    }
}
```

The corresponding source code is as follows:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" onclick="Stop()">Dream for Dreaming</button>
<audio hidden preload="auto" id="sound1" controls onplay="pauseOthers(this);">
    <source src="AUDIO FILES\Dream for Dreaming.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

However, this approach of applying different `Stop()` variables (e.g., `Stop2()`, `Stop3()`, etc.) each associated to different audio file ids is not efficient, and I clearly see that I need to use an alternative approach instead of using `getElementById`. I do not know how to program this JavaScript function to be global for all buttons selected. Instead of creating a separate function for each audio file, how can each audio file be called by a single JavaScript function to stop playing when I click on different buttons?

Comment: Use the jQuery delegation feature, so that you only need one handler for all the elements. `$("click", ".btn-block", Stop)`

Comment: @Pointy The problem is the fixed ID inside the common event handler, not just attaching a single handler to multiple elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call same onClick function for different buttons on the same HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317288/call-same-onclick-function-for-different-buttons-on-the-same-html-page)

Comment: @HereticMonkey That doesn't explain how to handle each button with different parameters.

Comment: @gre_gor We have rules about what to do when someone suggests a duplicate you disagree with: https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates/, last paragraph.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That's about already closed questions. Until that, you can review, if your suggested duplicate target is actually valid and retract your close vote, if it isn't.

Comment: @gre_gor I understand, you put some work into an answer and someone's calling you out. It takes a bit of steel to admit you've answered a duplicate. If not the one I linked to, then [give an onclick function to be executed to every element with a certain class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41783055/215552), or any number or others.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That one would fit (at least the accepted answer should make it work), your first one doesn't. Even if that were the problem, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements) would be a better dupe target. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797037/click-function-for-each-designated-class-item) looks closer to OP's problem.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, unfortunately, your suggested link posts are not in line with the approach that I was looking to learn to properly address my coding issue. User gre_gor properly answered my question with jQuery event delegation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group buttons and audio elements together inside HTML and then use `.closest` and `.find` to get the associated audio element.

It's also a good practice to separate HTML and JavaScript, so the usage of `on*` attributes is discouraged and you should attach event handlers through `.on` jQuery methods.
Ideally you would use [jQuery's event delagation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), but media event's don't work with that.

```js
function playStop()
{
    const audio = $(this).closest(".soundboard-item").find("audio").get(0);
    if(audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }
    else {
       audio.pause();
       audio.currentTime = 0;
    }
}

function pauseOthers() {
    $("#soundboard audio").not(this).each(function(index, audio) {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0
    });
}

$("#soundboard .soundboard-item").each(function(i, item) {
    $(item).find("button").on("click", playStop);
    $(item).find("audio").on("play", pauseOthers);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="soundboard">
    <div class="soundboard-item">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block">Star Wars</button>
        <audio hidden preload="auto" controls>
            <source src="https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/StarWars3.wav">
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="soundboard-item">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block">Cantina Band</button>
        <audio hidden preload="auto" controls>
            <source src="https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/CantinaBand3.wav">
        </audio>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction in terms of topics that I need to master and for showing me an elegant way of writing the source code to consolidate these different functions without relying on inline "on" attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the ID of the element to stop as a parameter in the `Stop` function.

```js
function Stop(id) {
  var Audio = document.getElementById(id);
  if(Audio.paused) {
      Audio.play();
    } else {
      Audio.pause();
      Audio.currentTime = 0
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" onclick="Stop('sound1')">Dream for Dreaming</button>
<audio hidden preload="auto" id="sound1" controls onplay="pauseOthers(this);">
    <source src="AUDIO FILES\Dream for Dreaming.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Then, simply change the ID of the element you would like to stop.

Comment: Thank you Tim! This simple fix allowed me to salvage the code that I already wrote and simplify my work.